# Failed to close connection using ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE

Tags: netty

I'm using Netty-5.0.0.Alpha1.I want to use **ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE** to close the connection, but it doesn't work.
I add an IdleStateHandler to the pipeline **.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(45, 0, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS))**

```
@Override    
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
   if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
      log.warn("closeing idle connection：{}", ctx.channel().attr("MAC_ADDRESS").get());
      //write an empty message to the client then close the channel
      ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
      }
   }

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    log.warn("channel closed");
   }
```

the server triggers an IdleStateEvent every 45 seconds but never call the channelInactive method.

```
>2017-08-24 14:00:35,170 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:01:20,170 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:02:05,171 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:02:50,172 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:03:35,172 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:04:20,172 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:05:05,173 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:05:50,173 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:06:35,174 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:07:20,174 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:08:05,175 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:08:50,176 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:09:35,176 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:10:20,176 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
>2017-08-24 14:11:05,176 WARN c.b.f.d.s.h.EventAndExceptionHandler [nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] closeing idle connection：******7925D7
```

but it works well at the most time, this situation only happened once.

Comment: Please update to latest 4.1 or 4.0 release and try again. 5.0.0x was deprecated and dropped for now.

Comment: Do you have other handlers in your pipeline?

Comment: @Ferrybig you mean another handler may get the IdleStateEvent, handle it and don't call the fireUserEventTriggered()  method? I'm totally sure I only override the userEventTriggered() in one handler.